# Windows Powershell and npm: passing "^" character in parameter string

Tags: powershell, npm, escaping

Windows 11 & Powershell 7.2.5: I'm trying to pass a regular expression in a parameter to my node.js app. The expression, `^@Test`, contains a ^ character, which is apparently also used to denote escape sequences in Powershell. Let's say this is my app:

```
const param = process.argv[2];
console.log(param);
```

When I run it this way:

```
node index.js "^@Test"
```

it works correctly and prints `^@Test`

But if I configure a script in `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
}
```

And I run:

```
npm run start "^@Test"
```

the leading ^ gets trimmed and it prints only `@Test`

Curiously, it does not get trimmed if ^ character is surrounded by a space on either side. So the following work correctly:

```
npm run start "^ @Test" // prints "^ @Test", correct
npm run start " ^@Test" // prints " ^@Test", correct
npm run start " ^ @Test" // prints " ^ @Test", correct
```

I tried escaping with ^^, `^ or ^, but neither works:

```
npm run start "^^@Test" // prints "@Test"
npm run start "`^@Test" // prints "@Test"
npm run start "\^@Test" // prints "\\@Test"
```

This also does not make a difference:

```
npm run start -- "^@Test" // prints "@Test"
```

With different quotes and without quotes it also does not work:

```
npm run start ^@Test // prints "@Test"
npm run start '^@Test' // prints "@Test"
```

Is this a bug or am I escaping it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Note: The following workarounds are required only if your argument does *not* contain spaces.

For *literal* arguments, use `--%`, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token):

```bash
npm run start --% "^@Test"
```

For *variable*-based arguments, use *embedded* quoting:

```bash
$var = 'Test'
npm run start "`"^@$var`""
```

---

You're seeing the **confluence of two surprising behaviors**, one by `cmd.exe` and the other by PowerShell:

- On Windows, `npm`'s entry point is a *batch file*, `npm.cmd`, and is therefore subject to `cmd.exe`'s parsing rules.

  - When a batch file is called from *outside* `cmd.exe`, `cmd.exe` still - *inappropriately* - parses the command line as if it had been submitted from *inside* a `cmd.exe` session. (Unfortunately, it has always worked this way and is unlikely to change).
  - Therefore, any `^` characters in an *unquoted* argument are interpreted as `cmd.exe` *escape character*; if `^` precedes a character with no special meaning (to `cmd.exe`), it is simply *removed* (e.g., `^@` turns into just `@`).
- PowerShell, which has its own quoting syntax and escape character, of necessity needs to *rebuild* command lines behind the scenes, so as to use only `"..."`-based quoting (double-quoting), as that is the only form of quoting CLIs are generally expected to support.

  - In this rebuilding process, double-quoting is employed *on demand*, namely based on whether a given argument *contains spaces*.
  - Thus, despite you having specified `"^@test"` on the *original* command line, as parsed by PowerShell, on the *rebuilt* command line it is *unquoted* `^@test` that is passed, which causes `npm`, due to being a *batch file*, to effectively drop the `^`, as explained above.

Note:

- PowerShell's behavior is defensible, as CLIs shouldn't parse their command lines as if they were *shell* command lines, which is what `cmd.exe` unfortunately does when batch files are called. Specifically, `^` should *not* be special when a batch file is called from outside a `cmd.exe` sessions.
- [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143) proposes that PowerShell implement *accommodations* for `cmd.exe` and other high-profile CLIs on Windows, so as to minimize such edge cases - unfortunately, it looks like that won't happen.

Comment: Great answer, very insightful - thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @mmm321321; my pleasure.